# Can I use for_each meta-argument with file function?

Tags: terraform

I am creating a bunch of random strings using `resource_string` resource block.
`length` is a required argument for this resource, and my goal is to read all the values for this variable from a file, using the `file` function.
Is there a way to do it?

Here is my code, along with the error:

```
resource "random_string" "any_string" {
    for_each = toset(file("string_number_file.txt"))
    length = each.key
}
```

```
cat string_number_file.txt
"10","12","13"
```

Goal is to create three random_strings, with above lengths.

Here is the error with above code:

```
Error: Invalid function argument
│
│   on main.tf line 9, in resource "random_string" "any_string":
│    9:     for_each = toset(file("string_number_file.txt"))
│
│ Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert string to set of any single type.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you have a different variable for the length or reading from the file is mandatory?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, thank you for your response. Yes, reading from file is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can **convert your file to json**, and then use that:

```
resource "random_string" "any_string" {
    for_each = toset(jsondecode(format("[%s]",file("string_number_file.txt"))))
    length = each.key
}
```